# SwiftUI, shadow only for container

Tags: swift, stack, swiftui, shadow

For example, I have this view:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TarifsScreen: View {  
    var body: some View {        
        GeometryReader { geometry in            
            VStack {                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text1")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text2")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text3")
                    Spacer()                    
                }
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .shadow(color: Color.white, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I apply shadow only for `VStack`, not for all elements inside `VStack`? May be I can do it with `ZStack` and two containers?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add background and apply shadow to it, like in below example

[image: demo]

```swift
  VStack {
    ...
  }
  .background(Color.white // any non-transparent background
    .shadow(color: Color.red, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
  )
  .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
```

Answer (score 9):

Also for a specific view:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("SwiftUI is Awesome").padding().background(
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .shadow(
                color: Color.gray.opacity(0.7),
                radius: 8,
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            )
    )
}
```

Reference from [here](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/adding-shadows-to-swiftui-views/).

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add fills or backgrounds, you can better override the `.shadow` modifier on the child views with a `.clear` color, to "stop" the shadow modifier from propagating down the hierarchy.

```
VStack { 
  // View with shadow
  ...
  VStack {
    // View without shadow
    ...
  }
  .shadow(color: .clear, radius: 0) // Override shadow
}
.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.3), radius: 10)
```

*For example if you are using a png image, the other answers would render the alpha channel with a solid color, which is not ideal.*