# How to draw just a round shadow without the actual view

Tags: swiftui, shadow

I'm a little stuck at the moment.
I would like to draw a round shadow
without giving the corresponding view an actual color.
My idea was the following:

```
Circle()
.fill(Color.clear)
.shadow(color: .red, radius: 10)
```

Unfortunately, the system only seems to draw shadows for views that also have a color and relates to the opacity value of that view.

Does anyone know a way around this.
I would be grateful for any tip.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow works only for opaque areas, so to mimic opacity we can use default system background color, like

```
Circle()
    .fill(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground))   // << here !!
    .shadow(color: .red, radius: 10)
```

and then you can place any content in overlay so it would look like over background with transparent shadowed circle.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60740418/12299030.